# I want to use Gmail within my website to send and receive mails. How can i Achieve that?

Tags: spring, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am having a website written in **JAVA SPRING and HIBERNATE**. I want to integrate gmail as apart of my website where my logged in users can use their gmail within my website. How can i do this?

Is there any way to create any mail server instead using gmail?

Anyway **my aim is to send and receive mails within the logged in users**, it will be helpful if that is achieved by gmail coz everything is cool there.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that, you need to follow the documentation for OAUTH2 at google.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol

Once you have access to their account, you can send and receive mail on their behalf. Getting users to grant you access to their accounts will be a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

The [JavaMail FAQ has instructions for using Gmail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned Spring, I assume you need a Spring bean that can send emails from within your project.

Check this - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html